# How to increase web-audio volume beyond 100%?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I saw that the web audio API only allows to set volume up-to 100%. Is there a way to allow a user to increase it beyond 100%? I thought doing it server side (e.g. modifying the original audio using [ffmpeg](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20change%20audio%20volume%20up-down%20with%20FFmpeg). I'm aware that this amplification might cause a loss of quality). Is there an easier way (preferebally client-side only)?

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain?

Comment: This only works if you are Spinal Tap.

Comment: @JohnHascall is this some kind of SO internal joke I'm missing? Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: @dimid Had to look it up too: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Up_to_eleven

Comment: @dimid The web audio `GainNode`'s `gain` value has no maximum: https://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/#attributes-6

Comment: @le_m Thanks! will check

Answer (score 1):

Use the gain Node. It has no maximum like le_m said.